# PHP Get values of checked box using foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of check boxes containing dates. Here's a preview of what I have so far:

```
// This code gets all the Sunday's in a month:
 function getSundaysForTheMonth($y, $m)
    {
        return new DatePeriod(
            new DateTime("first sunday of $y-$m"),
            DateInterval::createFromDateString('next sunday'),
            new DateTime("last day of $y-$m 23:59:59")
        );
    }
```

This is how I'm displaying it:

```
 // Get current Year and Month
    $currentYear = date('Y');
    $currentMonth = date('m');

    // Get month name
    $beginMonthName = date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $currentMonth, 10));


    echo "Select which Sunday(s) of the month of ". $beginMonthName . ". $currentYear . " ": \n<BR>";
    $i=0;

    // Display all Sundays for 3 months
    foreach (getSundaysForTheMonth($currentYear, $currentMonth) as $sunday) {
        $thisSunday = $sunday->format("m - d - Y");
        echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"date".$i."\" value=\".$thisSunday. \">".$thisSunday."<BR>";
        $i++;
    }
```

The idea was to do it with a foreach instead of this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="date0" value="2020-04-12 ">2020-04-12<BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="date1" value="2020-04-12 ">2020-04-19<BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="date2" value="2020-04-12 ">2020-04-26<BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="date3" value="2020-04-12 ">2020-03-03<BR>
```

Now I'm trying to get those values. I'm thinking the code should look similar to this but a bit different, since the input name has different names (date0, date1, date2, ...).

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['date'])) {

    foreach ($date as $sunday){
        echo $sunday."<br />";
        // Store $sunday in an array
    }
} else {
    echo "No selections";
}
?>
```

Any ideas on how I can make this work? 
 My goal is to store it in an array, in which will be put into a database.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array input name for your checkboxes, this will then get converted into an array in PHP:

```
foreach (getSundaysForTheMonth($currentYear, $currentMonth) as $sunday) {
    $thisSunday = $sunday->format("m - d - Y");
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"date[]\" value=\"$thisSunday\">$thisSunday<BR>";
}
```

This produces the following output ([demo](https://3v4l.org/BNabV)):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="04 - 05 - 2020">04 - 05 - 2020<BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="04 - 12 - 2020">04 - 12 - 2020<BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="04 - 19 - 2020">04 - 19 - 2020<BR>
<input type="checkbox" name="date[]" value="04 - 26 - 2020">04 - 26 - 2020<BR>
```

And in PHP you will get an array (in `$_POST['date']`) that looks like (if for example the first and third checkboxes were selected):

```
Array (
    [0] => '04 - 05 - 2020'
    [1] => '04 - 19 - 2020'
)
```

Note that if you are going to insert these values into a database you should put them into proper ISO-8601 format (`YYYY-MM-DD`) so change your `foreach` loop to look like:

```
foreach (getSundaysForTheMonth($currentYear, $currentMonth) as $sunday) {
    $thisSunday = $sunday->format("m - d - Y");
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"date[]\" value=\"" . $sunday->format('Y-m-d') . "\">$thisSunday\n<BR>";
}
```